# Having the problem for the checking BOOL value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

showing the error

/Users/rajinair/Desktop/xml/apitest/Classes/apicontroller.m: In function '-[apicontroller sendRequest]':
/Users/rajinair/Desktop/xml/apitest/Classes/apicontroller.m:167: warning: unused variable 'sysname'
/Users/rajinair/Desktop/xml/apitest/Classes/apicontroller.m: In function '-[apicontroller connectionDidFinishLoading:]':
/Users/rajinair/Desktop/xml/apitest/Classes/apicontroller.m:242: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

How can solve this.

```
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSDictionary *result = [json_string JSONValue];
NSArray *values = [result objectForKey:@"Result"];
BOOL errortest = [values valueForKey:@"isError"];//initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
if(errortest == FALSE)
{
    NSLog(@"Valid User");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid User");
}
```

Comment: How is `isError` represented in your JSON data? Is it a boolean (`true/false`) or a string or…? Also, is it possible that `Result` has more than one object containing `isError`? Consider editing your question and posting the original JSON data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `[values valueForKey:@"isError"]` returns the string representation of the boolean value(ie., *@"YES"*). You need to convert it to a bool value by using *NSString*'s *boolValue* method. So,

```
BOOL errortest = [[values valueForKey:@"isError"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Why would it return a string representation?

Comment: @Bavarious, Not necessarily. String is just one possibility. It can be of any other pointer type

Comment: And not every pointer points to an object that responds to `-boolValue`.

Comment: @Bavarious, Yes. But the value should be something that supports boolean value

Comment: Not really; it could easily be an array. There’s no way of being sure without knowing the structure of the JSON data.

Comment: @Bavarious, An array??? The key is named "isError". I don't think a good structured JSON would contain an array for the key "isError". If it contains an array (or dictionary) the key sould be something like "errors"

Comment: `-valueForKey:` is a Key-Value Coding method. As such, when applied to an array of objects/dictionaries it will return **an array** of all the values corresponding to a given key. I’ve never said that `isError` itself would be an array.

Comment: @Bavarious, Yes. But the key used here is "isError", so I said that the value would not be an array

Comment: You might want to read the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).

Comment: @Bavarious, Yes. Everyone should read that. You want to prove that you know everything and I don't know anything?

Comment: No; I’m just pointing out that it is possible for `valueForKey:@"isError"` to return an array even if `isError` itself is not an array, and the reason for that is the way KVC works.

Comment: @Bavarious, And you want me to agree with you. Alright. I agree

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
BOOL errortest = [[values objectForKey:@"isError"] boolValue];
```